# Symfony2: Redirect path on login failure being overridden by SonataAdmin login

Tags: security, symfony, redirect, authentication

I am using 2 login forms, one for the user and one for Sonata Admin.

The problem is when the user attempts to login and fails, the re-direct goes to the Sonata Admin login route and does not stay on the user login route/page.

I've looked at the documentation and tried to use `failure_path` but it still defaults back to the Sonata Admin login route.

It seems Sonata Admin bundle is overriding the re-direct path. I tried changing the order in the security.yml so the user section comes up first but that still doesn't fix the problem.

How can I fix this?

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: index
        anonymous: ~

    user:
        pattern:    ^/user
        form_login:
#                always_use_default_target_path: true
#                default_target_path: login_form
            failure_path: /user/login
            check_path: /user/login_check
            login_path: /user/login
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: index
        anonymous: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an authentication handler

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class SecurityHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{

    private $router;

    public function __contruct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        // only an example, make your own logic here
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        if (empty($referer)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
        } else {
            return new RedirectResponse($referer);
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // Edit it to meet your requeriments
        $request->getSession()->set('login_error', $error);
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login_route'));
    }

}
```

2) Register it as service

```
# src/Company/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml
security_handler:
    class: Company\Bundle\Handler\SecurityHandler
    arguments:  [@router]
```

3) Config to use this service as handler for login success and login failure, also you can use it in the `admin` firewall

```
# app/config/security.yml
firewalls:
admin:
    pattern:    ^/
    form_login:
        check_path: /login_check
        login_path: /login
        success_handler:    security_handler
        failure_handler:    security_handler
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: index
    anonymous: ~

user:
    pattern:    ^/user
    form_login:
#       always_use_default_target_path: true
#       default_target_path: login_form
        failure_path: /user/login
        check_path: /user/login_check
        login_path: /user/login
        success_handler:    security_handler
        failure_handler:    security_handler
    logout:
        path:   /user/logout
        target: index
    anonymous: ~
```

Comment: Sorry a bit new, but what is `$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');` and what goes in there?

Comment: It's the page `referer` it means that is the last page that visited the user when hits the login link, is not 100% secure beacuse it can be modified

Comment: Ok tried this, getting an error `Error: Call to a member function generate() on a non-object in /Handler/SecurityHandler.php line 38`, line 38: `return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login_form'));`

Comment: Looks like `$this->router` is not setted, var_dump it in the __contruct()

Answer (score 0):

You should configure you configurations from **specific to general**, because of general configuration can match any specific one.. So, try to change the order of your firewalls like this:

```
firewalls:
    user:
        pattern:    ^/user
        form_login:
    #       always_use_default_target_path: true
    #       default_target_path: login_form
            failure_path: /user/login
            check_path: /user/login_check
            login_path: /user/login
            success_handler:    security_handler
            failure_handler:    security_handler
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: index
        anonymous: ~
    admin:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            success_handler:    security_handler
            failure_handler:    security_handler
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: index
        anonymous: ~
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried to reorder it like in your example and the SonataAdmin login page still overrides my user login page. I even switched up the order in the routes to have the user routes load first, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem, and this is my solution. I also created a custom authentication handler:

```
class LoginFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel, HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, $logger = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($httpKernel, $httpUtils, $options, $logger);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $request->getSession()->set('_security.user_area.target_path', $request->get('redirect_url'));

        return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

I used the `_security.user_area.target_path` parameter for resetting the redirect_url if the authentication fails. Works perfectly!